# Openpyxl - how to unlock all cells in a worksheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, backend, openpyxl, host

I created an excel file using openpyxl. On default, worksheet cells are all locked. I just want to have row 1 and 2 to be locked, the rest should be unlocked and editable. I was planning to unlock all cells first,then locking the rows 1 and 2 but i'm stuck with the unlocking part. Is there a way to unlock all cells in a worksheet without iterating or looping columns/rows?

I tried this:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet("MySheet") 

col_range = ws['A1:M500']
for col in col_range:
     for c in col:
         c.protection = Protection(locked=False)

<< lock row 1 and row 2>>

ws.protection.password = 'somepassword'
```

But it takes so long, what more if i used ['A:XDF']

I need help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recently used this block of code to selectively lock some cells in a sheet

```
ws.protection.sheet = True #to lock the entire sheet
    for x in range(6, 100): # I wanted to lock rows 6 to 100 
        for y in range(1,100): #this is for locking columns 1 to 100 
            ws.cell(row = x, column = y).protection = Protection(locked=False, hidden=False)
```

Comment: As it's currently written, your answer is not answering the question. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).